# Google standard calendar on phone?

Tags: android

How to check if the standard [Google calendar application](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=summary) is available on the phone?

Comment: how did you do it? I'm facing the same issue, however the package manager is not enough

Answer (score 2):

You can check that using android's [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).